# Sort dictionary by number of values under each key

Tags: python, dictionary

Maybe this is obvious, but how do I sort a dictionary by the number of values in it?

like if this:

```
{
    "2010": [2],
    "2009": [4,7],
    "1989": [8]
}
```

would become this:

```
{   
    "2009": [4,7],
    "2010": [2],
    "1989": [8]
}
```

How would I only return key's that had > 1 value

```
 "2009": [4,7]
```

Answer (score 9):

Dictionaries are unordered, so there is no way of sorting a dictionary itself.  You can convert your dictionary to an ordered data type though.  In Python 2.7 or above, you can use `collections.OrderedDict`:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
d = {"2010": [2], "2009": [4,7], "1989": [8]}
ordered_d = OrderedDict(sorted(d.viewitems(), key=lambda x: len(x[1])))
```

Answer (score 2):

The standard `dict` type is essentially a hash table, and does not allow the user to re-order its keys. You can, however, achieve this using [`OrderedDict`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict):

```
In [1]: d = {
   ...:     "2010": [2],
   ...:     "2009": [4,7],
   ...:     "1989": [8]
   ...: }

In [2]: from collections import OrderedDict

In [5]: OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda (k,v):len(v), reverse=True))
Out[5]: OrderedDict([('2009', [4, 7]), ('2010', [2]), ('1989', [8])])
```

To filter out entries that are shorter than two elements:

```
In [7]: dict((k,v) for k,v in d.items() if len(v) > 1)
Out[7]: {'2009': [4, 7]}
```